# Как сформировать данные WooCommerce?

Tags: php, sql, циклы, woocommerce

Есть вот такие данные:

```
a:2:{s:3:"art";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:3:"ART";s:5:"value";s:6:"ART_ZN";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}s:18:"asdfawefseafvsafwe";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:18:"asdfawefseafvsafwe";s:5:"value";s:36:"asdfawefseafvsafweasdfawefseafvsafwe";s:8:"position";i:1;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}}
```

Это атрибуты из Woocommerce, не как не могу разобраться как сформировать новые данные из массива

Вот одна из неудачных попыток:

```
$count = 1;
            foreach($param_name as $param_n) {
            $count++;
            }

            $i = 0;
            foreach($param_name as $param_n) {
                $count_param_n = strlen($param_n);
                $count_param_value = strlen($param_value[$i]);

                $str = "a:$count:{";
                $str .= 's:';
                $str .= "$count_param_n";
                $str .= ':"';
                $str .= "$param_n";
                $str .= '";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:';
                $str .= "$count_param_n";
                $str .= ':"';
                $str .= "$param_n";
                $str .= '";s:5:"value";s:';
                $str .= "$count_param_value";
                $str .= ':"';
                $str .= "$param_value[$i]";
                $str .= '";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}';
                $str .= '}';
                $str .= '<br>';
                echo $str;

            }
```

Помогите пожалуйста сформировать запрос..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_data = serialize([
    'art' => [
        'name' => 'art', 
        'value' => 'ART_ZN', 
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я пробовал сериализовать данные, но я новичок в php. У меня просто не получается создать цикл сеарилизованных данных.

Comment: Если быть конкретней то мне надо что бы                                         
                                        $new_data = [
     'art' => ['name' => 'art','value' => 'ART_ZN',],
     'qwe' => ['name' => 'qwe','value' => 'ART_ZN',],
     ];                                                                                                                       генерировало циклом foreach